# RequireJS in custom theme. Working Example

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-dependencies

I try to add to my custom wordpress Theme requirejs because I do not want to use `wp_enqueue` over and over to inject used plugins and on the other side I do not want to mess the DOM from the beginning.

I followed a lot of tutorials what I got from google but none of theme is working. Is there a good working example how to use requirejs in a wrodpress theme properly?

Comment: I haven't ever used require in a WordPress project, but, you might try something like using grunt concatenation/minification so you can use a lot of js files for development, but only have to do a single wp_enqueue_script in your functions.php (or wherever).  That's what I usually do anyway if I'm doing a project that is going to be js heavy (for WordPress anyway).

Comment: Between I managed like adding manually require.js to the footer and call the main file over requires config file.

Comment: You enqueue requirejs as one file, then your main entry file as another with the requirejs dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `require` (commonJS modules) or `import/export` (ESM), and you can even mix both in the same project ("hybrid package" based on sub-folders). You will need a build tool to handle imports if you want to ensure cross-browser compatibility.

I have been using [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io) in a [recent project](https://github.com/openmindculture/kleiderordnung-berlin) as a lightweight alternative to [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) but you can choose any builder that can combine multiple script files into one single output file.

Then you will only need one enqueue script directive.

Install `esbuild`:

`npm install --save-dev esbuild`

and use it in your build target e.g. in `package.json`:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "build:core build:postcss build:js",
    "build:js": "esbuild src/js/scripts.js --bundle --sourcemap --target=es5 --outfile=themes/mytheme/js/scripts.js",
  },
  "type": "commonjs",
```

or change to `"type": "module"` to use `import` instead of `require`.